# Ansible Tower/AWX REST API launch job template with limit hosts

Tags: python, api, rest, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I'm trying to run AWX job template from REST API using Python. It is working fine when just running job template without any arguments, but I will need to specify the target hosts in the execution. When using get method I can see there is a 'limit' argument. Unfortunately when I run the code with python script.py job_id I'm getting the ignored field for limit: b'{"job":2133,"ignored_fields":{"limit":"server-PRC-05"},"id":2133,"type":"job","url":" etc..  I wasn't able to find working example for this.
Please find my python code below:

```
import sys
import requests
import json
templateid=sys.argv[1]
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
data_new = {'limit': 'server-PRC-05'}
res = requests.post('http://awx_host/api/v2/job_templates/'+templateid+'/launch/', 
verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'), data=json.dumps(data_new), headers=headers)
print (res.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

API `/api/v2/job_templates/{id}/launch/` received just `extra-vars` as data, add `limit` var as `extra-vars`.

> Additional strict `extra_vars` validation was added in Ansible Tower
> 3.0.0. `extra_vars` passed to the job launch API are only honored if one of the following is true:
>
> 1. They correspond to variables in an enabled survey
> 2. `ask_variables_on_launch` is set to True

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#extra-variables

Then set `ask_variables_on_launch=True` in that template.

Answer (score 1):

You need enable `ask_limit_on_launch` parameter and then pass limit as list (array) in the payload.

Your may look like this ->

```
data_new = {'limit': ['server-PRC-05']}
```

Observe `limit` is must list (array)

to enable `ask_limit_on_launch` refer link [Ansible tower API: pass inventory for a job in a POST payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687700/ansible-tower-api-pass-inventory-for-a-job-in-a-post-payload/71804727#71804727)